# How can I remove the last blank line of a wmic command?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

In a batch I want to use:

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=1" %I IN (wmic datafile where Name^="D:\\TOTO.EXE" get Version) DO (ECHO %I)
```

and want to restrict the ECHO, not having an `ECHO is on.` for the last line that is empty.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I don't want to have an `ECHO` for the last line that is empty

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=1" %I IN (wmic datafile where Name^="D:\\TOTO.EXE" get Version) DO (ECHO %I)
```

There are a few things you need to change for the above to work in a batch file:

1. Replace each single `%` with a double `%%`.
2. Add backticks `` (`) `` around the command that is executed by `for`.
3. Pipe `|` the `wmic` command to `findstr /r /v "^$"` to remove the blank lines (which will remove the `ECHO is on.` output.

Putting it all together, use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%i in (`wmic datafile where Name^="D:\\TOTO.EXE" get Version ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (echo %%i)
endlocal
```

You will get a single line output, similar to the following:

```
F:\test>test
6.1.7600.16385
```

---

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes.